# regex for weird string

Tags: regex

I need to help about writing regex for below string. I have tried lots of pattern but all failed.
I have a string like

```
package1[module11,module12,module13],package2[module21,module22,module23,module24,module25],package3[module31]
```

and I want to split this string like

```
package1
module11,module12,module13
package2
module21,module22,module23,module24,module25
package3
module31
```

I know it is weird to ask a regex from here but ...

Comment: which language are your working with? why do you want a regex? what if we can find a better solution?

Comment: without presuming a language, would it be safe to just replace `[` and `],` with a new line?

Comment: Yes right but, this is only displaying the how I want to split this string. All lines actually shows the separated string. Separate with new line may be a solution. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match using the pattern:

```
(\w+)\[(\w+(?:,\w+)*)\]
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/rPUEWBoU1d

The pattern is pretty simple, really:

- `(\w+)` - capture the first word (`package1`)
- `\[`
- `(\w+(?:,\w+)*)` - A sequence of at least one word (`module11`), followed by comma separated words (assuming they are well formed)
- `\]`

In all cases, you may want to change `\w` to your alphabet (maybe even `[^,\[\]]` - not comma or brackets). You also may want to check the whole string matches, as the above pattern may skip over unwanted parts (for example: `a[b]$$$$c[d]`)